# Condition for unique solution in $\Delta u -\lambda u= f$ when $\int_\Omega f\phi=0$ for all $\phi\in B_k$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

In the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem $\Delta u-\lambda u=f$ in $\Omega$ and $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$. I need to show if $\lambda=\lambda_k$ for some $k$ then tbe above equation has unique solution iff $\int f\phi=0$ for all $\phi\in B_k$ where $B_k$ is space of eigenfunction associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$.

One side I have proved. I could not able to prove that if $\int f\phi=0$ then there exists a unique solution when $\lambda=\lambda_k$;

Comment: I guess existence of a solution is not the issue (?). So let's assume you found two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$ to $\Delta u -  \lambda u = f$ in $\Omega$ and $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. What can you say about $u_1 - u_2$?

Comment: Yes let $w=u_1-u_2$ then $\Delta w-\lambda w=0$ and $w=0$ on boundary , I was thinking to multiply $w$ on both side and integrate to get $-\int_{\Omega}|Dw|^2=\lambda_k w^2$, but I don't know the sign of eigenvalue